Relationship between A/B testing and testing for (First-Order) stochastic dominance
Is there a relationship between A/B testing https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing and stochastic dominance, e.g. First-Order stochastic dominance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance? I had a hard time finding any explicit connection online.

they are different concepts: ab testing is just an experiment, and you could use a t-test on the group means or eg wilcoxon rank sum test( from stochastic dominance wiki): "In the case of non-intersecting[clarification needed] distribution functions, the Wilcoxon rank-sum test tests for first-order stochastic dominance.[6]"

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4613-8922-4_7 seems related
